# Combine duplicates inside a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do I combine the values of the duplicates keys of the dictionary inside of this list?

```py
lst = [{'CR Dashboard Group': 'Secure Servers', 'InstanceList': ['i-02424438d45214e92']}, 
{'CR Dashboard Group': 'IPA Servers', 'InstanceList': ['i-077ac3525e56a8c5f']}, 
{'CR Dashboard Group': 'Secure Servers', 'InstanceList': ['i-0d8c63982972b52bc']}]
```

Desired outcome is:

```py
lst = [
{'Crossroads Dashboard Group': 'Secure Servers', 'InstanceList': ['i-02401438d45214e92', 'i-0d8c63992972b52bc']}, 
{'Crossroads Dashboard Group': 'IPA Servers', 'InstanceList': ['i-077ac3525ee8a8c5f']}]
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: @Aziz Just updated the question with the desired result - thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @quamrana I'm not quite sure how to approach this. Nothing that I attempted came close. First I wanted to create a new dict with the items of the list, then try and append the values to the keys, but I wasn't able to create a new dict from the items so I have no code to show for it.

Comment: It might be easier to transform to a alternative representation first.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I agree, I'm just not sure how to go about that so if you have any ideas I'm all ears - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, collect into a dict of which uses (consistently ordered) tuples to store hashable data. Then, convert that to the desired representation.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def combine(ds):
    instances = defaultdict(list)

    for d in ds:
        key = tuple((k, d[k]) for k in sorted(d.keys()) if k != "InstanceList")
        instances[key].extend(d["InstanceList"])

    return [{**dict(k), "InstanceList": v} for k, v in instances.items()]
```

Test:

```
ds = [
    {"server": "A", "InstanceList": ["A1", "A2"]},
    {"server": "A", "InstanceList": ["A3", "A4"]},
    {"server": "B", "InstanceList": ["B1", "B2"]},
]

>>> combine(ds)
[
    {'server': 'A', 'InstanceList': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']},
    {'server': 'B', 'InstanceList': ['B1', 'B2']},
]
```