# How to properly "merge" complex python dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have n of very complex Python dictionaries with big depth level (~5) and I don't know how to merge them properly and fast, not to iterate over them for a milion times.

What is worth mentioning - that dicts have strict structure as you will see below.

I was trying solutions connected with:

- defaultdict
- merge operator

Version of Python - 3.9

```
d1 = {
  "name": "Louis",
  "places": [
    {
      "code": "A",
      "subplaces": [
        {
          "name": "Subplace name",
          "subsubplaces": [
            {
              "name": "subsub1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Subplace name2",
          "subsubplaces": [
            {
              "name": "subsub1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

d2 = {
  "name": "Louis",
  "places": [
    {
      "code": "B",
      "subplaces": [
        {
          "name": "Subplace name",
          "subsubplaces": [
            {
              "name": "subsub1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Subplace name2",
          "subsubplaces": [
            {
              "name": "subsub1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

d3 = {
  "name": "Louis",
  "places": [
    {
      "code": "A",
      "subplaces": [
        {
          "name": "Subplace name X",
          "subsubplaces": [
            {
              "name": "subsub1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And in that case output should be

```
d_merged = {
  "name": "Louis",
  "places": [
    {
      "code": "A",
      "subplaces": [
        {
          "name": "Subplace name",
          "subsubplaces": [
            {
              "name": "subsub1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Subplace name2",
          "subsubplaces": [
            {
              "name": "subsub1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Subplace name X",
          "subsubplaces": [
            {
              "name": "subsub1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "B",
      "subplaces": [
        {
          "name": "Subplace name",
          "subsubplaces": [
            {
              "name": "subsub1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Subplace name2",
          "subsubplaces": [
            {
              "name": "subsub1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `d_merged` can only contain one name (Louis). Is that intended?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq - yes

Comment: I think you may need to aggregate into an intermediate representation that is easier to add items to, similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71100774/combine-duplicates-inside-a-list-of-dicts/71100908#71100908. Maybe transform the input to something easier, too.

Comment: Do you expect the updates to happen in order or by some other criterion? For example if you merge 3 dicts, with `"name"` being `"a"`, `"a"` and `"b"`, would you expect the name to be `"a"`, because it's first, or most common, or `"b"` because it's last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is quite specific, so universal solution is not possible. I'd suggest you to merge all *"places"*, *"subplaces"* and *"subsubplaces"* in nested dictionary to clean up all possible duplicates and then modify data to match desired format.

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_places(*dicts):
    if not dicts:
        return
    
    # check all dicts have same names
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
    g = groupby(dicts, itemgetter("name"))
    if next(g, True) and next(g, False):
        raise ValueError("Dictionaries names are not equal")

    places = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))  # set values are unique
    for d in dicts:
        for place in d["places"]:
            for subplace in place["subplaces"]:
                for subsubplace in subplace["subsubplaces"]:
                    places[place["code"]][subplace["name"]].add(subsubplace["name"])

    return {
        "name": d["name"],  # always exists as dicts aren't empty
        "places": [
            {
                "code": code,
                "subplaces": [
                    {
                        "name": name,
                        "subsubplaces": [
                            {"name": subsubplace}
                            for subsubplace in subsubplaces
                        ]
                    }
                    for name, subsubplaces in subplaces.items()
                ]
            }
            for code, subplaces in places.items()
        ]
    }
```

Usage:

```py
result = merge_places(d1, d2, d3)
```

Output:

```json
{
    "name": "Louis",
    "places": [
        {
            "code": "A",
            "subplaces": [
                {
                    "name": "Subplace name",
                    "subsubplaces": [
                        {
                            "name": "subsub1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Subplace name2",
                    "subsubplaces": [
                        {
                            "name": "subsub1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Subplace name X",
                    "subsubplaces": [
                        {
                            "name": "subsub1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "code": "B",
            "subplaces": [
                {
                    "name": "Subplace name",
                    "subsubplaces": [
                        {
                            "name": "subsub1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Subplace name2",
                    "subsubplaces": [
                        {
                            "name": "subsub1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your representation of data has a lot of non unnecessary details, we can reduce them by this solution:

```python
from typing import Dict, List


dicts = [
    {
        "name": "Louis",
        "places": [
            {
                "code": "A",
                "subplaces": [
                    {
                        "name": "Subplace name",
                        "subsubplaces": [
                            {
                                "name": "subsub1"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Subplace name2",
                        "subsubplaces": [
                            {
                                "name": "subsub1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Louis",
        "places": [
            {
                "code": "B",
                "subplaces": [
                    {
                        "name": "Subplace name",
                        "subsubplaces": [
                            {
                                "name": "subsub1"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Subplace name2",
                        "subsubplaces": [
                            {
                                "name": "subsub1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Louis",
        "places": [
            {
                "code": "A",
                "subplaces": [
                    {
                        "name": "Subplace name X",
                        "subsubplaces": [
                            {
                                "name": "subsub1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]


def merger(dicts: List[Dict]) -> Dict:
    result = {}
    for d in dicts:
        name = d["name"]
        if not name in result:
            result[name] = {}
        places = d["places"]
        for p in places:
            code = p["code"]
            if not code in result[name]:
                result[name][code] = []
            result[name][code].extend(p["subplaces"])
    return result


print(merger(dicts=dicts))
```

The output will be:

```python
{
    'Louis':{
        'A':[
            {'name': 'Subplace name', 'subsubplaces': [{'name': 'subsub1'}]},
            {'name': 'Subplace name2', 'subsubplaces': [{'name': 'subsub1'}]},
            {'name': 'Subplace name X', 'subsubplaces': [{'name': 'subsub1'}]}
        ],
        'B':[
            {'name': 'Subplace name', 'subsubplaces': [{'name': 'subsub1'}]},
            {'name': 'Subplace name2', 'subsubplaces': [{'name': 'subsub1'}]}]
    }
}
```

If you want your desired output it's easy to change this one to your desired output, but this on is more readable and maintainable.

Comment: I'd use `set` instead of list to avoid dups.

Comment: You want to use set in where ?

Comment: `result[name][code] = []` there

Comment: but dict objects are  unhashable types

Comment: for this we could use a dict from `Subplace name` to this objects

Comment: So you could have dublicates in subsubplaces

Comment: Are you sure this produces the expected output? `assert merger(dicts=dicts) == d_merged`

Comment: I said it's a little different but it's better and if you want the actual result it's very easy to convert it to that one